# Project SQLite database onto ListView

Tags: android, sqlite, listview, android-fragments, simplecursoradapter

I am working from a fragment java class, and I want to change the listview of a fragment to contain some items from a SQLite database.

Here is the code for the populating:

```
private void populateListView() {
    Cursor cursor = myDb.getAllRows();

    String[] fromFieldNames = new String[] {DBAdapter.KEY_VAK, DBAdapter.KEY_LOKAAL};
    int[] toViewIDs = new int[] {R.id.textVak, R.id.textLokaal};
    SimpleCursorAdapter myCursorAdapter;
    myCursorAdapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(getActivity().getBaseContext(), R.layout.layout, cursor, fromFieldNames, toViewIDs, 0);

    ListView myList = (ListView) getView().findViewById(R.id.listView);
    myList.setAdapter(myCursorAdapter);
}
```

And here is the code for the DBAdapter:

```
public class DBAdapter {

private static final String TAG = "DBAdapter"; //used for logging database version changes

// Field Names:
public static final String KEY_ROWID = "_id";
//public static final String KEY_DAG = "dag";
//public static final String KEY_UUR = "uur";
public static final String KEY_VAK = "vak";
public static final String KEY_LOKAAL = "lokaal";

public static final String[] ALL_KEYS = new String[] {KEY_ROWID,KEY_VAK, KEY_LOKAAL}; // KEY_DAG, KEY_UUR

// Column Numbers for each Field Name:
public static final int COL_ROWID = 0;
//public static final int COL_DAG = 1;
//public static final int COL_UUR = 2;
public static final int COL_VAK = 1;
public static final int COL_LOKAAL = 2;


// DataBase info:
public static final String DATABASE_NAME = "db";
public static final String DATABASE_TABLE = "Rooster";
public static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1; // The version number must be incremented each time a change to DB structure occurs.

//SQL statement to create database
private static final String DATABASE_CREATE_SQL = "CREATE TABLE " + DATABASE_TABLE + " (" + KEY_ROWID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, " + KEY_VAK + " TEXT, "    + KEY_LOKAAL + " TEXT"  + ");";

private final Context context;
private DatabaseHelper myDBHelper;
private SQLiteDatabase db;


public DBAdapter(Context ctx) {
    this.context = ctx;
    myDBHelper = new DatabaseHelper(context);
}

// Open the database connection.
public DBAdapter open() {
    db = myDBHelper.getWritableDatabase();
    return this;
}

// Close the database connection.
public void close() {
    myDBHelper.close();
}

// Add a new set of values to be inserted into the database.
public long insertRow(String task, String date) {
    ContentValues initialValues = new ContentValues();
    initialValues.put(KEY_VAK, task);
    initialValues.put(KEY_LOKAAL, date);

    // Insert the data into the database.
    return db.insert(DATABASE_TABLE, null, initialValues);
}

// Delete a row from the database, by rowId (primary key)
public boolean deleteRow(long rowId) {
    String where = KEY_ROWID + "=" + rowId;
    return db.delete(DATABASE_TABLE, where, null) != 0;
}

public void deleteAll() {
    Cursor c = getAllRows();
    long rowId = c.getColumnIndexOrThrow(KEY_ROWID);
    if (c.moveToFirst()) {
        do {
            deleteRow(c.getLong((int) rowId));              
        } while (c.moveToNext());
    }
    c.close();
}

// Return all data in the database.
public Cursor getAllRows() {
    String where = null;
    Cursor c =  db.query(true, DATABASE_TABLE, ALL_KEYS, where, null, null, null, null, null);
    if (c != null) {
        c.moveToFirst();
    }
    return c;
}

// Get a specific row (by rowId)
public Cursor getRow(long rowId) {
    String where = KEY_ROWID + "=" + rowId;
    Cursor c =  db.query(true, DATABASE_TABLE, ALL_KEYS, 
                    where, null, null, null, null, null);
    if (c != null) {
        c.moveToFirst();
    }
    return c;
}

// Change an existing row to be equal to new data.
//public boolean updateRow(long rowId, String vak, String lokaal) {
//  String where = KEY_ROWID + "=" + rowId;
//  ContentValues newValues = new ContentValues();
//  newValues.put(KEY_VAK, vak);
//  newValues.put(KEY_LOKAAL, lokaal);
//  // Insert it into the database.
//  return db.update(DATABASE_TABLE, newValues, where, null) != 0;
//}


private static class DatabaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper
{
    DatabaseHelper(Context context) {
        super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase _db) {
        _db.execSQL(DATABASE_CREATE_SQL);           
    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase _db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
        Log.w(TAG, "Upgrading application's database from version " + oldVersion
                + " to " + newVersion + ", which will destroy all old data!");

        // Destroy old database:
        _db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + DATABASE_TABLE);

        // Recreate new database:
        onCreate(_db);
    }
}
```

}

The error I get is as follows:

> java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.ListView.setAdapter(android.widget.ListAdapter)' on a null object reference

Comment: Do you got a ListView element with android:id="@+id/listview" in your fragment's XML layout file?

Comment: @zkminusck Yes I do.

Comment: Where do you call this function? Is it before `onCreateView` of your fragment is called?

Comment: @0xDEADC0DE No, that isn't the problem either.